# Different display for selected value on Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I would like to know what are the codes for having text that will change according to the selected value in the dropdown menu.

[image: Example Image]

I know the codes for creating the dropdown with the numbers value:

`<select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>`'

But I don't know how to make the selection of different value to display content that will change accordingly. Can you provide me some support? I'm working with

https://www.wix.com/

Comment: what language are we into? and that probably is a call back from server which has different set of data stored for different option value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This May help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option></select>'

<p id="ele1">foo</p>

<script>
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var ele1 = document.getElementById('ele1');
select.addEventListener('change',function(e){ 

//alert(this.value);
if(this.value=='2'){
ele1.innerHTML="bar"
}else if(this.value=='3'){
ele1.innerHTML="foo bar"
}else if(this.value=='4'){
ele1.innerHTML="foo bar foo bar"
}

})

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sharon Shreger you need code for selected values appear to text-box (when change the dropdown)?

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23tga2L5/) have code for change text box value based on dropdown selection